# Mongoid Syntax Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, railscasts

In [episode 189 of Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association), there is a named scope in the User model which is as follows:

```
field :roles_mask,      :type => Integer
ROLES = %w[admin moderator author]

named_scope :with_role, lambda { |role| {:conditions => "roles_mask & #{2**ROLES.index(role.to_s)} > 0"} }

 # roles related
 def roles=(roles)
  self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.sum
 end

 def roles
   ROLES.reject { |r| ((roles_mask || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero? }
 end

 def role_symbols
  roles.map(&:to_sym)
 end
```

How would one get it to work on Mongoid as I tried the a number of options and could not get it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That episode of Railscasts was really designed for databases that don't support arrays as native types (which Mongoid does). Then you could just create a scope which uses one of the [array query criteria](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#any_in).

For example:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :email
  field :roles, :type => Array

  ROLES = %w[admin moderator author]

  class << self
    def with_role(*args)
      any_in(:roles => args)
    end
  end
end
```

This example would allow you to pass in either a single role `User.with_role("admin")` or an array of roles `User.with_role("moderator", "author")`, with the latter returning users who are either moderators or authors.

Comment: theTron, thanks so much for the answer but the roles are being saved as bitmask column and not an array column. I guess I can get rid of the bitmask and convert it to an array column to store the roles but I was wondering if there was a way to do a similar thing Ryan is doing with mongoid.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're set on using the bit mask? The Array ends up making the implementation _a lot_ easier in the long run - and certainly a lot more readable.

Comment: I ended up using arrays like you recommended. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native map reduce mongoDB machanism which is exposed through mongoid using for_js method 
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Criteria:for_js

```
ROLES.each_with_index do |role, role_index|
  scope "#{role.to_s.pluralize}", -> { self.for_js("(this.roles_mask & (1 << role_val)) > 0", role_val: role_index) }
end
```

This will give scopes in the form of:

```
User.admins
User.moderators
User.authors
```